# Installing teams app with messaging extension for all team members

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a question regarding installation of messaging extension app. Actually I assumed that I can upload my app to teams admin center "teams apps" and afterwards it is ready to use for all teams and all team members. I already did this steps with an app showing a custom tab and everything worked fine.
Across the documentation I only found information on how to sideload apps. That is working but only for the logged in user, not for other team members. Thats why I think app package seems to be ok.

So, what is the correct way to install an app containing a messaging extension to my teams so that all team members can use it? Does app manifest need to provide some special content?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No one has an idea? So just to simplify my question:
Is it possible to install an app with a messaging extension to all users at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Admin has the privilege to install an app from the admin center by assigning [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-policies#assign-a-custom-teams-policy-to-users) to users. Please have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-policies) document.